# Find end of the line in a regular expression using Notepad++

Tags: regex, find, newline, notepad++

I am working with [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) and I would like to find the new line (after the hyphen, optional space and some characters in the end line).

I have came up with something like this:

- `-[ ]?.*\n`

I have also tried:

- `-[ ]?.*(\n)`
- `-[ ]?.*(\r\n)`
- `-[ ]?.*[\r\n]`
- `-[ ]?.*[\n]`

None of these worked. I am working on Windows if it matters.

Comment: Have you tried `$` for the end of line?

Comment: Have you turned on the 'extended/regular expression' search mode?

Comment: @Chimoo Yes I did. That's why it worked for me for e.g. `-[ ].*`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you do not actually need to *match* the line break, you can simply use `$` which is the anchor for end of a line.

Comment: Omg. I forgot that I can use `$`. Thanks a lot :). I need this for finding untranslated words in my words list ;)

Comment: Years later, this saved me a ton of time and frustration! I'm working in a pipe separated value format, and I needed to modify a file to have pipes "|" at the end of each line. Find "$" and replace with "|" while in regex mode worked perfectly.

Comment: Note that in Notepad++, there is a checkbox titled ". matches newline" in the Find and Replace dialog window. If that box is not checked, any ".*" match will terminate upon reaching a linebreak.

Comment: This isn't under the `Replace` tab like I expected, but it is under the `Find in Files` tab.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

`\R` (capital R) will grab any end of line characters in Notepad++.

I usually do something like this:

`-.+\R` will grab everything from the hyphen through to the end of line as well as any return characters.

`$` for end of line and `^` for start of line are your friends too.

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Comment: The link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at docs.notepad-plus-plus.org."*

Comment: Working link: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions