# Notepad++ how to replace or add a certain symbol near the end of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++

So i have a bunch of lines, that i need to add `:` or replace with another certain symbol near the end of the line so it doubles at the last `:`

`ROWERS:TREADMILL-1000M:SITUPS@100:CRUNCHES@10:TEST`

So it will become

`ROWERS:TREADMILL-1000M:SITUPS@100:CRUNCHES@10::TEST`

I thought it would be something simple such as `(:$)`but no i am having no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To double the last `:` you may

**Find What**: `:[^:\r\n]*$`
**Replace with**: `:$0`

The `:[^:\r\n]*$` pattern matches a `:` char that is followed with any 0+ chars other than `:`, CR and LF.

Note that if you want to avoid adding a `:` in case the last `:` is already doubled, add `(?<!:)` lookbehind that will fail the match if there is a `:` before a `:`:

```
(?<!:):[^:\r\n]*$
^^^^^^
```

See NPP S&R settings and demo:

[image]

Comment: @Luuk Yes, but it may capture more than needed if the subsequent lines do not contain `:`, and the match memory buffer may grow redundantly, slowing down replacement process.

Comment: According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505123/find-end-of-the-line-in-regular-expression-using-notepad) the '$' should match end-of-line, which indeed seems to be broken in version 7.8.4

Comment: Anywayz, i created a question at Notepad++ for this: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/18978/regular-expression-end-of-line

Comment: @Luuk `$` is not broken, it works as expected. Same as `[^:]*` - *any 0+ chars other than `:`*, thus including any newlines, carriage returns and other vertical whitespace. I think you expect NPP regex to work the same way as Vim's where character classes do not match across linebreaks unless you add `\_` before them, or as in VSCode, where you need to add `\r` or `\n`. NPP is just different from those editors. Multiline texts have always been a pain for the text editor developers. Notepad2 regex does not allow matching across lines at all.

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew and everyone else, works perfect